# MIN and MAX value by string in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have database table. The ORM for it is:

```
public long Id { get; set; }
public System.Guid AttrId { get; set; }
public System.Guid ProdId { get; set; }
public string Value { get; set; }

public virtual Attributes Attributes { get; set; }
public virtual Products Products { get; set; }
```

As you can see value is a string type. I'm trying to get min and max values by this field (some values represented as double). So here is my method for this:

```
public double[] GetMaxMinVals(Guid attrId)
{
    double[] res = new double[2];
    using(entityContext = new SiteDBEntities())
    {
        res[0] = entityContext.ProductAttributes.Where(x=>x.AttrId == attrId)
            .Min(x => Convert.ToDouble(x.Value));
        res[1] = entityContext.ProductAttributes.Where(x => x.AttrId == attrId)
            .Max(x => Convert.ToDouble(x.Value));
    }

    return res;
}
```

But I getting exception:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double ToDouble(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

So how can I search for a string value like a decimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can cast the `Value` to double then use `Max/Min`:

```
public double[] GetMaxMinVals(Guid attrId)
    {
        double[] res = new double[2];
        using(entityContext = new SiteDBEntities())
        {
            res[0] = entityContext.ProductAttributes
              .Where(x => x.AttrId == attrId)
              .Select(x => x.Value)
              .Cast<double>()
              .Min();
        }

        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Now i know another one EF funtion and where to use it  ;-)

Comment: Did it work? Did you try? Cause when I tried it after I wrote the answer, I realized that it wouldn't for your case. If it works, I probably missed something.

Comment: Okay, I am more than glad then!

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is your query will be translated into `SQL` and run on the database, and Entity Framework doesn't know how to translate `Convert.ToDouble` into valid SQL code.

So you could cast to `double` as below, which will be later converted to `SQL CAST AS` statement.

```
res[0] = entityContext.ProductAttributes.Where(x=>x.AttrId == attrId).Min(x => (double)x.Value);
res[1] = entityContext.ProductAttributes.Where(x => x.AttrId == attrId).Max(x => (double)x.Value);
```

Comment: Thanx for explaining!

Answer (score 1):

In EF Dbcontext don't support "Convert.ToDouble", you can fix same that:

```
public double[] GetMaxMinVals(Guid attrId)
        {
            double[] res = new double[2];
            using(entityContext = new SiteDBEntities())
            {
                res[0] = entityContext.ProductAttributes.Where(x=>x.AttrId == attrId).Min(x => (double)x.Value);
                res[1] = entityContext.ProductAttributes.Where(x => x.AttrId == attrId).Max(x => (double)x.Value);
            }

            return res;
        }
```