# get Current record selected in group by lambdada expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have this Table
[image]
and I want to group by `lifeplusecaseId` field and return all fields with group by

I've tried this

```
   var query = db.ApplicantCenterDistance.GroupBy(a => a.LifeplusCaseId)
                    .Select(s => new {
                        Id = s.Key,      
                        MinDistance = s.Min(m => m.Distance),
                        Duration = s.Min(m => m.Duration),
                       items=s.ToList(),
                    
                    }).Where(x=>x.MinDistance!=" ").ToList();
```

but I got a problem that said:

```
"System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: (a.LifeplusCaseId), 
ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression: "
```

I don't know how can I return all records.

the error is :

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression '(GroupByShaperExpression:
> KeySelector: (a.LifeplusCaseId),
> ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression:
> EntityType: ApplicantCenterDistance
> ValueBufferExpression:
> (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
> IsNullable: False
> )
> )
> .ToList()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'

Comment: off topic: `MinDistance = s.Min(m => m.Distance),` will perform a string comparison. You can get quite unexpected results. Like this here: `new string [] {"123", "99" }.Min(x => x)` will return `123` as the minimum

Comment: sorry mate I cannot reproduce your problem. which version of the entity-framework are you using?

Comment: @MongZhu ,It's ef 6.4.4

Comment: me too. then something seems to be missing here. Please post the entire exception message and probably even the stacktrace

Comment: @MongZhu I added it

Comment: Is distance a string field? you should include the structure of this type

Comment: @ChrisSchaller yes it is

Answer (score 0):

Errors like this were common in older versions of EF, I have tested this syntax in EF 6.4.4 and find no problems, however there may be other issues with the structure of your types that can affect the *Linq to SQL* expression evaluation.

> Your error message does not match the EF 6.4.4 nomenclature, which indicates something else is at play here, however this this error matches EF Core 3.1+.

Firstly, as the error is specifically around your use of `.ToList()`, so remove it from the expression, EF6 will support returning the grouping expression and projection via `AsEnumerable<>`. Either of the following will work in EF6:

```
.Select(s => new {
    Id = s.Key,      
    MinDistance = s.Min(m => m.Distance),
    Duration = s.Min(m => m.Duration),
    items = s
})
```

Or projection via `.AsEnumerable<ApplicantCenterDistance>()`

```
.Select(s => new {
    Id = s.Key,      
    MinDistance = s.Min(m => m.Distance),
    Duration = s.Min(m => m.Duration),
    items = s.AsEnumerable<ApplicantCenterDistance>()
})
```

If you are still experiencing issues you could also move the filter condition to before the projection, this allows the projection (and therfore the `.ToList()`) to be evaluated on the client side, which is what the exception message and the associated [MS Docs article](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038) is hinting at:

```
var query = db.ApplicantCenterDistance
                .GroupBy(a => a.LifeplusCaseId)
                .Where(x => x.Where(x => x.Min(m => m.Distance) != " ")
                .Select(s => new {
                    Id = s.Key,      
                    MinDistance = s.Min(m => m.Distance),
                    Duration = s.Min(m => m.Duration),
                    items=s.ToList(),                    
                }).ToList();
```

### UPDATE: EF Core

If you are executing this in EF Core 3.1+ then one option is to pull the entire recordset into memory on the client, and group it there. If the numer of results was always going to be very large anyway, then this wont have much of an impact, given that you were already keeping all the items within each group:

```
var dataList = db.ApplicantCenterDistance.ToList();
var data = dataList
                .GroupBy(a => a.LifeplusCaseId)
                .Select(s => new {
                    Id = s.Key,      
                    MinDistance = s.Min(m => m.Distance),
                    Duration = s.Min(m => m.Duration),
                    items=s.ToList(),                    
                }).Where(x=>x.MinDistance!=" ").ToList();
```

### UPDATE: MIN on string fields

as `Distance` is a string, `MIN` may not evaluate the correct numeric comparison if you actually want the minimum value, to do this you will need to cast this into a numeric type.

> **NOTE:** you can use this syntax in any of the above queries, however if you want the evaluation performed in the database you will need to cast to a `double`, in the last client side example you can use any C# code that you wish to cast the value.

```
MinDistance = s.Where(m => m != " ").Min(m => (double)m.Distance),
```

Here we are first filtering out the values that can not be cast to a numeric, you may need to adjust this depending on if your data set includes nulls or zero length strings. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37587135/1690217) for more details.

Comment: I can not move the filter condition to before the projection because the MinDistance  in not know there!

Comment: Sorry @amirkian typeo in my own example, are you saying that neither of the other two options worked for you either? I have to ask again, are you sure this is EF 6.44 and not Core?

Comment: No ,I'm Using .net coe.what should I do?

Comment: you know you told @MongZhu ,It's ef 6.4.4 ... I've updated the response